# Kafka 0.10.2 consumers getting massive number of duplicates

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a fairly simple Kafka setup - 1 producer, 1 topic, 10 partitions, 10 KafkaConsumers all with the same group ID, all running on a single machine. When I process a file, the producer quickly creates 3269 messages, which the consumers happily start consuming. Everything runs fine for a while, but at a certain point the consumers start consuming duplicates - LOTS  of duplicates. In fact, it looks like they just start consuming the message queue over again. If I let it run for a long time, the database will start receiving the same data entries 6 or more times. After doing some tests with logging, it looks like the consumers are re-consuming the same messages with the same unique message names.

As far as I can tell, no re-balancing is happening. Consumers are not dying or being added. It's the same 10 consumers, consuming the same 3269 messages over and over until I kill the process. If I just let it go, the consumers will write dozens of thousands of records, massively increasing the amount of data that really should be going into the database.

I'm fairly new to Kafka, but I'm kind of at a loss for why this is happening. I know Kafka doesn't guarantee exactly-once processing, and I'm ok with a couple duplicates here and there. I have code to prevent persisting the same records again. However, I'm not sure why the consumers would re-consume the queue over and over. I know that Kafka messages aren't deleted after they are consumed, but if all the consumers are in the same group, the offsets should prevent this, right? I understand a little bit about how offsets work, but as far as I know, they shouldn't be getting reset if there is no re-balancing, right? And the messages aren't timing out as far as I can tell. Is there a way for me to get my consumers to consume everything in the queue once-ish and then wait for more messages without re-consuming the same stuff forever?

Here are the proprties I pass in to the producer and consumers:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("acks", "all");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("batch.size", 16384);
        props.put("linger.ms", 1);
        props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
        props.put("group.id", "MyGroup");
        props.put("num.partitions", 10);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

        MyIngester ingester = new MyIngester(args[0], props);
```

Answer (score 1):

To me this seems to be an issue with acknowledging the receipt.
Try the following properties

```
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "100");
```